# ExcelPackage and 98 thousand rows

Tags: c#, excel, excelpackage

I want to write an excel file (2007) with the codeplex excelpackage but it is taking a lot of time to write the excel file. 
I didn't find any method that it could accept a datasource.

the piece of my code:

```
var newFile = new FileInfo(GlobalVariables.Compare2007Path);

using (var excelpackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
  var myWorkbook = excelpackage.Workbook;
  myWorkbook.Worksheets.Add("sheetname");

  var xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets["sheetname"];

  //loop the data and fill the columns
  var rowCount = 2;
  foreach (var compare in objCompare)
  {
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 1).Value = compare.adserverIdSite.ToString();
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 2).Value = compare.site;
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 3).Value = compare.adserverIdZone.ToString();
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 4).Value = compare.zone;
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 5).Value = compare.position;
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 6).Value = compare.weekday;
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 7).Value = compare.oldimps.ToString();
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 8).Value = compare.olduu.ToString();
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 9).Value = compare.oldimpsuu.ToString();
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 10).Value = compare.newimps.ToString();
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 11).Value = compare.newuu.ToString();
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 12).Value = compare.newimpsuu.ToString();
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 13).Value = compare.diffimps.ToString();
    xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 14).Value = compare.diffimpsperc.ToString();
    rowCount++;
  }
  excelpackage.Save();
}
```

Or are there other options besides excelpackage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found my solution for the performance of the excel package. It's a patch you need to apply on the excelPackage. The patch can be found [here](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/SourceControl/PatchList.aspx). Look for the id : 1042 or for the update 1233 (more features in that patch).

With the patch, you are able to add a datatable on an empty sheet. The adding of 98000 records with 14 columns was done in seconds.

Comment: I was using ExcelPackage following this tutorial: http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20a%20template%20to%20create%20an%20Excel%20spreadsheet (sqlreader... while.read makes it damn slow for big data). I applied the patch suggested above (1233) and used the new LoadFromDataTable method and a SqlDataAdapter instead of the sqlreader, as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809320/trouble-loading-sql-data-reader-data-into-datatable I got a huge performance improvement (from "timeout" server error to "now it works... in a few seconds!").

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will do it.

You might want to look at the SpreadsheetGear Explorer Sample Solution (for C# or VB) which is installed with SpreadsheetGear. There is a sample under Advanced -> Performance which shows the fast way to populate cells. On my machine (overclocked Intel QX6850) it creates 50,000 rows by 4 columns in 0.05 seconds.

You can download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) which will install the SpreadsheetGear component and the SpreadsheetGear Explorer sample mentioned above.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: +1 I had the same issue with excelpackage not scaling out well after the first couple of hundred rows due to its use of Xpath. Tried adding in the patches on codeplex, no improvement for me. I refactored to use the spreadsheetgear 2010 demo and it was so much faster and scales linearly both for creating and reading. We will be purchasing the full version soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have used (and bought) [SmartXL](http://www.smartxls.com/) for creating Excel files. It's not free but it saved me a lot of time. You can try it for free for 30 days.