# Trouble loading SQL Data Reader data into DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, datatable, sqldatareader

```
string query = "select * from cfo_daily_trans_hist";
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
                       cnnString))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query);
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    connection.Open();

                    var result = command.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
                    datatable.Load(result);
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

So the `var result` is created through the `ExecuteReader();` and `HasRows` is `true`, and it shows the correct amount of fields. However, the `DataTable` that I create from it is empty.

What am I doing wrong? I'm 99% sure it's getting data, but I don't know how to find it through the `SqlDataReader` object to make sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of a `SqlDataReader`, use a `SqlDataAdapter`.

```
SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
myAdapter.Fill(datatable);
```

With a `SqlDataAdapter`, you don't need to explicitly call `SqlConnection.Open()` and `SqlConnection.Close()`.  It is handled in the `Fill()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add "COALESCE" in your sql command statement ... if you have some NULL value in your query result, you will have problem with dataTable

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.