# DataTable not loading SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, sqldatareader

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
                datatable.Load(reader);

                return datatable;
            }
        }
    }
```

Running this code returns an empty DataTable. However, looping through `reader.Read()` and printing to the debug console shows that the reader has data and it prints the expected data. Also, When I expand the reader object during debugging, hasRows is true and the field count is right for the number of columns returned.

There was a similar post here
[Trouble loading SQL Data Reader data into DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809320/trouble-loading-sql-data-reader-data-into-datatable)
but the answer essentially was, just don't use it, use a `SqlDataAdapter`. I would prefer to use it and the `DataTable` has a load method that takes an IDataReader `DataTable.Load(IDataReader)`. I just don't know why the reader is working when I print it to the debug window but not when I load it into the `DataTable`. Am I just overlooking something?

Comment: @SonerGönül I don't see a Fill method on the SqlDataReader  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How about using `SqlDataAdapter` and using it's `Fill` method?

Comment: @SonerGönül I can use the `SqlDataAdapter` but I am just curious why the appropriate method on the DataTable isn't working... SqlDataReader is much faster and I would prefer to use it. Here is some info on the differences http://stackoverflow.com/a/1676809/3866019

Comment: I doubt there's a difference - `DataTable.Load` uses a data adapter internally anyway :) All those "benefits" of using `SqlDataReader` that are in the answer you linked only apply when you don't use the reader to fill a `DataTable` (which shouldn't be unexpected, since data adapter simply fills a data table using the data reader; if you do that manually using a data reader instead, where would you expect any benefit? You're doing the exact same thing. The cost is in the data table.). Be careful about accepting advice like this without understanding what actually happens - it's going to hurt.

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/143/convert-data-reader-to-data-table there are only small differences between your code and this article, but give it a try.

Comment: In any case, `DataTable.Load` works just fine for me. If you keep everything as is and use a data adapter to fill the table instead, does it actually work? Do you have multiple result sets? What does the command do?

Comment: @Luaan you make a good point about the performance. I still don't like stepping away from it without knowing why it won't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out I was just overlooking something and this is actually not an issue at all. The original code actually works fine. The preview of the `DataTable` object when debugging shows `{}` and looked empty to me. 
[image]

Then there was a property on the object called `ExtendedProperties` that had `Count = 0`, which obviously isn't a row count but I just glossed over and got `Count = 0` stuck in my head.

[image]

If you find yourself in the same situation, scroll down when hovering the object and expand the `Rows` and you should see your row count in there. [image]

I got duped on this one... sorry for the stupidity on my part and thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: So how did you fix the error, you didnt mention this just what you noticed

Comment: Gossh...thats horrible

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this see if it works...

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand,connection);
    DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
    dap.Fill(datatable);
    return datatable;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338188/datatable-not-loading-sqldatareader?noredirect=1#comment56418080_34338188

Comment: why have you shared this link? @SonerGönül

Comment: As @SonerGönül said, I can go this route, but I would still like to know why the `DataTable.Load()` method doesn't work as expected or if I am just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SqlDataReader` or `DataAdapter`, both will work. Write the return statement after closing the connection. Try if it works.